# Is exist methods for tune GETNEXT for many many many of sequential OIDs?

Tags: ethernet, net-snmp

I am coding in C some tool for monitoring ethernet switch by snmp v1 and Net-SNMP lib.
In one of the step I get FDB table from switch.
It gets by request `getnext` with OID `.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1`. After I get for example:

```
getnext .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1     answer .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.144.2.166.50.206.43 3
getnext .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.144.2.166.50.206.43   answer .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.144.2.166.50.206.63      6
getnext .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.144.2.166.50.206.63   answer .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.144.2.166.50.206.126    4
getnext  .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.144.2.166.50.206.126 answer  .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.41.0.21.100.59.187.78    26
getnext .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.41.0.21.100.59.187.78   answer NULL
```

Unfortunately some switch ports have a very large number of rows and the full cycle of `getnext` takes long time.

Is there any method to get all rows of `getnext`
OID `.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1` etc. at one request?

Or may be have other methods for get its requests faster?

Comment: For SNMPv1, no.  If you could use SNMPv2 or later, you could use the `GETBULK` request to query more OIDs in one request.

Comment: Castaglia sorry but getBULTnot work for me. If I right understand the GETBULK request can do more then one request but for get FDB I am must request the OID by GETNEXT, after I receive answer and request answer by the GETNEXT and etc by the full cycle until I receive NULL. Sorry for my english